# Searching information with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in a project where I need to do the following. I have to work with two files; File1 and File2.

The Macro needs to go into File1 get an id#(0123456789) and find it in File2.

Once it finds the id# in File2 it copies information from the same sheet found in different cells in the same row.

Once the information is found it will be exported into a third file.

Notes: Column names cannot be hard coded like - column = "F" or "G", etc. - because columns might be in different letter every time I want to find the id#. id# will need to be found by the column name, such as range("A1:Z1"). If column name = id#Name in range("A1:Z1") then look for id# in that column.

I am new with VBA, don't know where to start at, but if any of you can point me out to the right direction I will do it. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Read some vba tutorials and figure out your logic. You can try For Each loop then check if item meets requirements in conditional statements, then set a variable to that ID and do the same for file 2 where file 2s conditional statement is the ID# you wanted from file1